# Powershell foreach Exchange Online InboxRule issue

Tags: powershell, loops, office365

I'm having an issue when trying to complete my script.

I'm trying to create a rule for couple of users:
(if message arrives from (x), move to Inbox).
This is the script I wrote:

```
 $names = @{"name1@name.com","name2@name.com"}
```

### Loop

```
foreach($name in $names){
    Write-Host "Moving the message for $name"
    new-inboxrule -Name "MoveFromMailchimp" -Mailbox $name -MoveToFolder 
    "$name:\Inbox" -From "senderEmailAddress" -StopProcessingRules: $false
}
```

However it throws an error upon $name:\Inbox, saying it does not want to take ":".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your variable in the string.

Try:
`"$($name):\Inbox"`